# How to select element generated from JavaScript?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to select the Wireless button on the pop-up that is generated in the same window. It does not generate any iFrames and I cannot locate any elements inside this **Wifi-Connect** window.

Anyone got any ideas?

I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ext-gen1481']/div/li[2]/div/a"
```

And I've also tried via CSS.

Code I'm trying to select:

```
<img class="x-tree-node-icon nsm-wifi-icon-wireless" unselectable="on" src="/scripts/ext-3/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt=""/>
<a class="x-tree-node-anchor" tabindex="1" href="" hidefocus="on">
<span unselectable="on">Wireless</span>
```

HTML code:

```
<document>
<html class=" ext-strict">
<head>
<body id="ext-gen3" class=" ext-gecko ext-gecko3 ext-linux syno-diskless router" style="background: transparent url("resources/images/theme/router/default_wallpaper/01.jpg?v=7742") no-repeat scroll center center / cover ;">
<img id="sds-wallpaper" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
<!-- Don't contain any text node to avoid IE insertBefore bug -->
<div id="sds-apply-preview-form" style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; left: -10000px;">
<script src="synodefs.cgi?v=1540399973" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/scripts/uistrings.cgi?lang=enu&v=1514770623" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/webfm/webUI/uistrings.cgi?lang=enu&v=1514770623" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="uistrings.cgi?lang=enu&v=1514770623" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/scripts/prototype-1.7.2/prototype.js?v=1540399953" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/scripts/ext-3/adapter/ext/ext-base.js?v=1540399953" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/scripts/ext-3/ext-all.js?v=1540399953" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/scripts/ext-3/ux/ux-all.js?v=1540399953" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="/scripts/scrollbar/flexcroll.js?v=1540399953" type="text/javascript"/>
<style type="text/css">.flexcroll-hide-default { overflow: hidden !important; } </style>
<script src="/synoSDSjslib/sds.js?v=1540399966" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="desktop.js?v=1540399973" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript">SYNO.SDS.Session = {    "configured" : true,    "diskless" : true,    "enable_syno_token" : "yes",    "fullversion" : "1514764831",    "hostname" : "SynologyRouter",    "isLogined" : false,    "lang" : "enu",    "login_background_color" : "#FFFFFF",    "login_background_enable" : false,    "login_background_ext" : ".jpg",    "login_background_hd_enable" : false,    "login_background_pos" : "center",    "login_background_seq" : 0,    "login_background_type" : "fromDS",    "login_enable_fp" : 0,    "login_logo_enable" : false,    "login_logo_ext" : ".jpg",    "login_logo_pos" : "center",    "login_logo_seq" : 0,    "login_only_bgcolor" : false,    "login_style" : "tpl1",    "login_version_logo" : true,    "version" : "1514764831" } ;</script>
<script type="text/javascript"/>
<div class="pre-load-x-window-br"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1002" class=" x-tip-invalid" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2147483647; visibility: hidden; display: none;">
<div id="ext-comp-1003" class="x-tip" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20002; visibility: hidden; width: 159px; left: 847px; top: 368px; display: none;">
<div id="sds-taskbar-shadow" style="visibility: visible;"/>
<div id="sds-taskbar" class="x-column-layout-ct">
<div id="sds-desktop" class="sds-desktop-view-show no-transition" tabindex="-1" style="height: 358px; width: 1301px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;">
<ul id="ext-gen142" class="sds-desktop-shortcut">
<div id="ext-gen190" class="x-window-proxy"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1101" class=" x-window sds-window-v5" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: 301px; top: 118px; width: 700px;">
<div id="ext-gen273" class="x-window-proxy"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1151" class=" x-window sds-window-v5 x-resizable-pinned" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: 40px; top: 40px; width: 600px;">
<div id="ext-gen448" class="x-window-proxy"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1237" class=" x-window sds-window-v5 x-window-noborder x-window-plain x-resizable-pinned" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: 70px; top: 70px; width: 800px;">
<div id="ext-gen1030" class="x-window-proxy" style="display: none;"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1563" class="x-window syno-app-nsm-wifi sds-window-v5 x-resizable-pinned active-win" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9033; visibility: visible; left: 80px; top: 17px; width: 1100px;">
<div class="x-window-tl">
<div id="ext-gen1020" class="x-window-bwrap">
<div class="x-window-ml">
<div class="x-window-mr">
<div id="ext-gen1023" class="x-window-mc">
<div id="ext-gen1021" class="x-window-body" style="width: 1100px; height: 563px;">
<div id="ext-comp-1564" class=" x-border-layout-ct" style="width: 1100px; height: 563px;">
<div id="ext-comp-1561" class=" x-panel syno-ux-modulelist x-panel-noborder x-tree x-border-panel scroll-at-top scroll-at-bottom scroll-at-left scroll-at-right" style="width: 234px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div id="ext-gen1033" class="x-panel-bwrap">
<div id="ext-gen1034" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader x-panel-body-noborder flexcrollactive" style="padding: 0px 16px 0px 12px; width: 206px; height: 563px; overflow: hidden; border-width: 0px; position: relative; text-align: left;" tabindex="0">
<div id="ext-gen1034_mcontentwrapper" class="mcontentwrapper" style="width: 206px; height: 563px; top: 0px; left: -12px; border-bottom: 0px solid black; text-align: start; padding: 0px 16px 0px 12px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; z-index: 2;">
<div id="ext-gen1034_contentwrapper" class="contentwrapper" style="position: relative; top: 0px; width: 100%; display: block; padding: 0px; left: 0px;">
<ul id="ext-gen1035" class="x-tree-root-ct x-tree-arrows" style="width: 234px;">
<div class="x-tree-root-node">
<li id="ext-gen1379" class="x-tree-node">
<li class="x-tree-node">
<div class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable" unselectable="on" ext:tree-node-id="SYNO.SDS.NSMWifi.Wireless.Main">
<span class="x-tree-node-indent"/>
<img class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow" src="/scripts/ext-3/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt=""/>
<img class="x-tree-node-icon nsm-wifi-icon-wireless" unselectable="on" src="/scripts/ext-3/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt=""/>
<a class="x-tree-node-anchor" tabindex="1" href="" hidefocus="on">
<span unselectable="on">Wireless</span>
</a>
</div>
<ul class="x-tree-node-ct" style="display:none;"/>
</li>
<li class="x-tree-node">
<li class="x-tree-node">
<li class="x-tree-node">
</div>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="ext-gen1034_scrollwrapper" class="scrollwrapper" style="width: 234px; height: 563px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="ext-comp-1562" class=" x-panel x-panel-noborder x-border-panel" style="left: 240px; top: 0px; width: 860px;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="ext-gen1022" class="x-window-bl x-panel-nofooter">
</div>
<a id="ext-gen1029" class="x-dlg-focus" tabindex="-1" href="#"/>
<div id="ext-gen1040" class="x-resizable-handle x-resizable-handle-north x-unselectable x-window-handle"/>
<div id="ext-gen1041" class="x-resizable-handle x-resizable-handle-south x-unselectable x-window-handle"/>
<div id="ext-gen1042" class="x-resizable-handle x-resizable-handle-east x-unselectable x-window-handle"/>
<div id="ext-gen1043" class="x-resizable-handle x-resizable-handle-west x-unselectable x-window-handle"/>
<div id="ext-gen1044" class="x-resizable-handle x-resizable-handle-northeast x-unselectable x-window-handle"/>
<div id="ext-gen1045" class="x-resizable-handle x-resizable-handle-northwest x-unselectable x-window-handle"/>
<div id="ext-gen1046" class="x-resizable-handle x-resizable-handle-southeast x-unselectable x-window-handle"/>
<div id="ext-gen1047" class="x-resizable-handle x-resizable-handle-southwest x-unselectable x-window-handle"/>
</div>
</div>
<div id="ext-gen76" class="sds-launch-icon-dragging-proxy x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: 111px; top: 209px;">
<div id="sds-appview" class=" syno-sds-appview white-scrollerbar sds-desktop-view-animate x-hide-offsets" style="width: 1301px; height: 358px;" tabindex="-1">
<div id="ext-gen108" class="appview-icon-dragging-proxy x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen122" class="appview-icon-dragging-proxy x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-comp-1064" class=" sds-previewbox x-hide-display"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1067" class=" sds-searchbox x-hide-display sds-searchbox-init-state">
<div id="ext-gen156" class="nsm-home-device-list-dragged x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen159" class=" x-panel sds-port-disabled-panel sds-tray-panel" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; width: 300px;">
<div id="ext-comp-1110" class=" x-panel sds-tray-panel" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; width: 340px;">
<div id="ext-comp-1125" class=" x-panel sds-notify-tray-panel" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen300" class="x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop x-grid3-col-dd" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen302" class="col-move-top"/>
<div id="ext-gen303" class="col-move-bottom"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1151-rzproxy" class="x-resizable-proxy x-unselectable"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1160" class=" x-panel sds-tray-panel sds-filemonitor-tray-panel x-panel-noborder x-grid-panel syno-ux-gridpanel" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; width: 300px;">
<div id="ext-gen365" class="x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop x-grid3-col-dd" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen367" class="col-move-top"/>
<div id="ext-gen368" class="col-move-bottom"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1174" class=" x-panel sds-tray-panel sds-filemonitor-tray-panel x-panel-noborder x-grid-panel syno-ux-gridpanel" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-comp-1184" class=" x-panel sds-tray-panel sds-filemonitor-tray-panel x-panel-noborder x-grid-panel syno-ux-gridpanel" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-comp-1189" class=" x-panel sds-tray-panel sds-filemonitor-tray-panel x-panel-noborder x-grid-panel syno-ux-gridpanel" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px; width: 300px;">
<div id="ext-gen429" class="x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop x-grid3-col-dd" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen431" class="col-move-top"/>
<div id="ext-gen432" class="col-move-bottom"/>
<div id="ext-gen536" class="x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop x-grid3-col-dd" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen538" class="col-move-top"/>
<div id="ext-gen539" class="col-move-bottom"/>
<div id="ext-gen556" class="x-dd-drag-proxy x-dd-drop-nodrop x-grid3-col-dd" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: hidden; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;">
<div id="ext-gen558" class="col-move-top"/>
<div id="ext-gen559" class="col-move-bottom"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1237-rzproxy" class="x-resizable-proxy x-unselectable"/>
<div id="ext-gen591" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px; visibility: hidden; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; font-family: verdana,tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; line-height: 14px; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: normal; width: auto;"/>
<div id="ext-gen742" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px; visibility: hidden; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; font-family: verdana,tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; line-height: 20px; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: normal; width: auto;"/>
<div id="ext-comp-1563-rzproxy" class="x-resizable-proxy x-unselectable" style="z-index: 9037;"/>
<div id="ext-gen1158" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px; visibility: hidden; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-weight: 700; font-family: verdana,tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; line-height: 20px; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: normal; width: auto;"/>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

This is the actual code is I just view the page source not through the Firefox inspector:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="resources/images/icon_tile.png?v=4398" />
<meta name="application-name" content="Synology Router - SynologyRouter" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#246BB3"/>
<meta name="description" content="Synology Router provides a full-featured network attached storage (NAS) solution to help you manage, backup and share data among Windows, Mac and Linux easily." />
<meta name="keywords" content="Multitasking,Web Application,Personal Cloud" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?v=4399" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/images/icon_dsm_96.png?v=4398" sizes="96x96"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/images/icon_dsm_64.png?v=4398" sizes="64x64"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/images/icon_dsm_48.png?v=4398" sizes="48x48"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/images/icon_dsm_32.png?v=4398" sizes="32x32"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/images/icon_dsm_16.png?v=4398" sizes="16x16"/>
<title>Synology&nbsp;Router&nbsp;-&nbsp;SynologyRouter</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scripts/ext-3/resources/css/ext-all.css?v=1540399953" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scripts/ext-3/resources/css/xtheme-gray.css?v=1540399953" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/scripts/ext-3/ux/ux-all.css?v=1540399953" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/synoSDSjslib/sds.css?v=1540399966" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/desktop.css?v=1540399973" />
<style type="text/css">
@import url("modules/MyDSCenter/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/PhotoViewer/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/NetworkTools/style.css?v=1540399973");
@import url("modules/LogCenter/style.css?v=1540399971");
@import url("modules/nsm-AdminCenter/style.css?v=1540399982");
@import url("modules/nsm-Home/style.css?v=1540399967");
@import url("modules/Share/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/FileTaskMonitor/style.css?v=1540399970");
@import url("modules/BandwidthControl/style.css?v=1540399982");
@import url("modules/TrafficReport/style.css?v=1540400015");
@import url("modules/PollingTask/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/WelcomeTip/style.css?v=1540399973");
@import url("modules/VideoPlayer2/style.css?v=1540400046");
@import url("modules/HelpBrowser/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/SupportForm/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/WelcomeApp/style.css?v=1540399973");
@import url("modules/ThumbConvertProgress/style.css?v=1540399982");
@import url("modules/PkgManApp/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/Bodymovin/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/ChartLib/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/DSMNotify/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/PersonalSettings/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/Utils/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/nsm-Wifi/style.css?v=1540399999");
@import url("modules/WelcomeInstaller/style.css?v=1540399973");
@import url("modules/MobileSetup/style.css?v=1540399973");
@import url("modules/SecurityScan/style.css?v=1540399983");
@import url("modules/AudioPlayer/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/DataDrivenDocuments/style.css?v=1540399986");
@import url("modules/BackupReplicationApp/style.css?v=1540399998");
</style>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("modules/FileBrowser/style.css?v=1540399970");
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="3rdparty/addon-azure_blob/style.css?v=1540400017" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="3rdparty/addon-aws_s3/style.css?v=1540400083" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="3rdparty/addon-sfr_s3/style.css?v=1540399968" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="3rdparty/addon-hicloud_s3/style.css?v=1540400023" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="3rdparty/SafeAccess/style.css?v=1537934111" />

</head>
<body>
<img id="sds-wallpaper" />
<!-- Don't contain any text node to avoid IE insertBefore bug -->
<div id="sds-login-dialog-form" style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; left: -10000px;"><form id="login-form" class="x-plain-body" method="POST" action="login.cgi" target="login_iframe" onsubmit="return true;"><input type="text" id="login_username" name="username" maxlength="256" /><input type="password" id="login_passwd" name="passwd" maxlength="256" /><input type="text" id="login_otp" name="OTPcode" maxlength="8" autocomplete="off" /><input type="submit" id="login_submit" style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; left: -10000px;" tabindex="-1" /></form><iframe id="login_iframe" name="login_iframe" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" style="display: none;"></iframe></div>
<div id="sds-apply-preview-form" style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; left: -10000px;"><form id="preview-form" class="x-plain-body" method="POST" action="modules/ControlPanel/modules/dsm.cgi" target="preview_iframe" onsubmit="return true;"><input type="submit" id="preview_submit" style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; left: -10000px;" tabindex="-1" /></form><iframe id="preview_iframe" name="preview_iframe" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" style="display: none;"></iframe></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="synodefs.cgi?v=1540399973"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/uistrings.cgi?lang=enu&v=1514770623"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webfm/webUI/uistrings.cgi?lang=enu&v=1514770623"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="uistrings.cgi?lang=enu&v=1514770623"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/prototype-1.7.2/prototype.js?v=1540399953"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ext-3/adapter/ext/ext-base.js?v=1540399953"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ext-3/ext-all.js?v=1540399953"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ext-3/ux/ux-all.js?v=1540399953"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/scrollbar/flexcroll.js?v=1540399953"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/synoSDSjslib/sds.js?v=1540399966"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="desktop.js?v=1540399973"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">SYNO.SDS.Session = {
   "configured" : true,
   "diskless" : true,
   "enable_syno_token" : "yes",
   "fullversion" : "1514764831",
   "hostname" : "SynologyRouter",
   "isLogined" : false,
   "lang" : "enu",
   "login_background_color" : "#FFFFFF",
   "login_background_enable" : false,
   "login_background_ext" : ".jpg",
   "login_background_hd_enable" : false,
   "login_background_pos" : "center",
   "login_background_seq" : 0,
   "login_background_type" : "fromDS",
   "login_enable_fp" : 0,
   "login_logo_enable" : false,
   "login_logo_ext" : ".jpg",
   "login_logo_pos" : "center",
   "login_logo_seq" : 0,
   "login_only_bgcolor" : false,
   "login_style" : "tpl1",
   "login_version_logo" : true,
   "version" : "1514764831"
}
;</script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="pre-load-x-window-br"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something simple like `//span[.='Wireless']` should work given the HTML you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the element with text as **Wireless** is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) generated element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='x-tree-node-icon nsm-wifi-icon-wireless']//following::a[1]/span[text()='Wireless']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: How did you work out the XPath for this scenario, is there a guide somewhere?

Comment: Well, it should work flawless. This _xpath_ uses a dynamic strategy and you can find the references in the [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).

Comment: I'm trying to select this class '//*[@class='onoffswitch-label']' when I use Firebug it shows it but selenium is unable to locate it?

Comment: @zstring Can you please raise a new question with your new requirement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748508/how-to-get-a-dynamic-xpath

Answer (score 0):

In your given XPath you are using an id for the first reference point. I'm assuming you have done the same with cssSelector also.

Since these ids are generated randomly it is different every time. Your given code and your XPath has a different id for example.

Try the following CSS selectors instead,

**CSS:**

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[ext:tree-node-id='SYNO.SDS.NSMWifi.Wireless.Main'] > a");
```

**XPath:**

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@ext:tree-node-id='SYNO.SDS.NSMWifi.Wireless.Main']/a");
```

If the pop-up elements are not selectable then you may need to switch to the active element.

Answer (score -1):

If it is not showing any locators and if its getting generated in the same window then chances are it can be an alert.
If it is an alert then simply try 
driver.switchTo().alert().accept() or (any other action u want to perform).
Hope that helped ...